# What is it about metal elements that means their conduction and valence bands overlap, as opposed to non-metal elements where there is no overlap?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I can't see why metals have overlapping bands and a higher Fermi level compared to Non-metals where there is no overlap and the Fermi level is not in the conduction band.

Comment: Probably just because they do and the valance theory works, not because they make sense or are derived some canonical theory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formation of the overlap in metal electron bands](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30214)

Comment: I don't think it's answering the question I asked.

Comment: Metals have an unfilled band, not overlapping conduction/valence bands. So, why should all bands be just filled or empty?

Comment: Don't non-metals also have unfilled bands?